# Do new versions of wordpress org removed the delete post within the post?

Tags: wordpress

I have been a long time user of wordpress and i have been looking for hours in the new interface of the post page the delete entrance button.
In some older blogs i am able to find it but the new ones i am not finding it.
The only way i have been able to find it is in "Quick edit"

I am using wordpress version: 6.3

Do i have to configure something to showing it?
Where can i find the delete post within the post?

Thanks in advance

Here are two screenshots of two blogs with the same problem:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps on how to show the delete post button in the new interface of the post page:

- Go to **Settings > Writing**.
- In the **Formatting** section, enable the **Show delete link in post toolbar** option.
- Click on the **Save Changes** button.

Once you have enabled this option, the delete post button will appear in the toolbar at the top of the post edit screen.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your answer. It is super weird, I am at /wp-admin/options-writing.php and there is no Formatting section showing...i created a custom theme...maybe is because of this?

Comment: It is possible that the Formatting section is not being displayed because you are using a custom theme. It might have overridden the default settings.

To check this, you can try the following:

Go to **Appearance > Themes**. Click on the **Edit** button for your custom theme. In the theme editor, search for the line of code that starts with **add_filter('show_writing_settings_formatting', '__return_false');**.
If you find this line of code, delete it. Save your changes and try going to **Settings > Writing** again. The **Formatting** section should now be displayed.

Comment: If you are still unable to see the Formatting section, here are some other possible reasons why the Formatting section might not be displayed:

- You are using an outdated version of WordPress. (try updating to latest wordpress)
- You have a plugin that is conflicting with WordPress. (try disabling all plugins)

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a lot for helping me with this ;). I was still not able to solve it, i am using the latest version of wordpress (6.3) and the version of PHP is 8.0. I disabled all plugins with no success. But well is not a big deal. I will close the issue if i don't find the answer. Thanks again

Comment: Hmm, try also temporarily switching to a default WordPress theme like Twenty Twenty-One or Twenty Twenty-Two. If the Formatting section appears, it means your custom theme is the culprit.

Comment: I've just tried by switching to Twenty Twenty-One and nothing, the button is still missing. Thanks again for keeping track of this. I appreciate all your help

Comment: If you are sure you're logged in as an administrator or a user role that has the capabilities to delete posts then as a last resort, you might consider installing WordPress on a subdomain or local environment and seeing if you experience the same issue on a fresh installation with no plugins and the default theme.

Comment: Just made a fresh install of 6.3 and can definitely see Trash button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple things and nothing worked work, i wanna thanks @bestwebhosting.guide for his advices.

Finally i migrated my wordpress to a new hosting provider and it worked again, it seems that my previous hosting services lacked a lot of php extensions.
As an advice to anyone: maybe your hosting allow you to install wordpress, but this doesn't mean it has all the PHP extensions.

Here is the list of extensions recommended by wordpress: https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/server-environment/#php-extensions
Find a provider that has all of them or at least the ones that you are going to need!!